# Redirect old site to a subdirectory and install WordPress as root

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I moved my old static site to a subdirectory named old. I also installed WordPress on the root. Now i want to implements a 301 redirect for my old static site. The problem is that i want to redirect http://www.example.com/x to /old/x unless there is a x in the web root (infact i dont want redirect also WordPress articles, pages etc.). I tried with this:

```
# Map http://www.example.com/x to /old/x unless there is a x in the web root.    
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/old/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /old/$1

#WordPress default .htaccess
# BEGIN s2Member GZIP exclusions
<IfModule rewrite_module>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)s2member_file_download\=.+ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|\?|&)no-gzip\=1
    RewriteRule .* - [E=no-gzip:1]
</IfModule>
# END s2Member GZIP exclusions

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It doesnt work, i think there is a sort of conflict.

Comment: You moved your site to /old. now you want to move it again to another directory? Your question is not clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I moved my old static site to /old. Now i want to implements a 301 redirect (for my old site), but i installed WordPress on the root. How should i implement redirect?

Comment: That's not going to work well. Wordpress directs all non real file/directory requests to index. php. If your old site are real files/directories you need to remove the two conditions in your first rule.  If it were me, I wouldn't use subdirectories for reasons like that. I'd do a subdomain. It's just as easy to setup. old.example.com

Comment: I removed the two conditions but i get the 500 error code. "a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.".

Comment: Even if i use a subdomain there is the same problem. How do i redirect to the old site without causing conflicts with WordPress (installed in the root)?